# Mounting SIP Power Module with 1.7mm Pin Pitch @ 8 Amps

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pins, prototyping

I'm attempting to mount a GE NQR010A0X4Z power module ([datasheet here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/167/NQR010A0X-477178.pdf)) on a prototype board or custom PCB and am not sure what I can do besides directly soldering wires to the pins (which seems very hacky).

At first, I was looking to create a simple breakout board but the narrow pin pitch restricts me from creating traces wide enough to handle the current and creating heavier traces also get's too expensive.

What are my options?

Comment: Have the traces soldered over to thicken without the extra board cost. This is popular with ATX computer power supply's and small AC to D.C. converters. You can usually at least triple the thickness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option I have seen done many times:

Have the traces soldered over to thicken without the extra thick copper board cost. This is popular with budget ATX computer power supplies and small AC to DC converters. You can usually at least triple the thickness.